# Limit Behaviour of Equivalent Processes

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, limsup-and-liminf

Let $(X_t)_{t\ge 0}$ and $(Y_t)_{t\ge 0}$ be two real-valued stochastic processes on some probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ such that their finite-dimensional distributions coincide. 
Assume furthermore that 
$$ \limsup\limits_{t\to \infty} \; X_t \; = \; +\infty \quad \text{ and } \quad \liminf\limits_{t\to \infty} \; X_t \; = \; -\infty$$
almost surely.
 
I expect that in this case it also holds 
$$ \limsup\limits_{t\to \infty} \; Y_t \; = \; +\infty \quad \text{ and } \quad \liminf\limits_{t\to \infty} \; Y_t \; = \; -\infty$$
almost surely. Is this generally true?